# How to change background color on textbox xaml from app.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

I have created a Windows Phone app using C# and XAML.

Now I want to change the `background-color` on my `textbox` if it `GotFocus`. How can I trigger that from app.xaml? I want to code once so that it can be implemented in all of my `textbox`es.

I have tried using VisualState, but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

have you checked this question? I think you have the same problem

[changing background color of container when textbox is in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441059/changing-background-color-of-container-when-textbox-is-in-focus)

Comment: Yes i have, but the problem is I don't have Style.Trigger in Windows Phone